# Strange StackOverflow exception

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((Program)3);

        Console.WriteLine("Execution complete.");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static implicit operator Program(int asd)
    { return 10; }
}
```

Which throws a StackOverflow exception at the last line (`{ return 10; }`). And I cannot figure out why, since there should be enough space on the stack for everything.

I am learning about the `operator` keyword and implicit/explicit converting, so I made this little example to test some tings.

Comment: What does the code suppose to do? convert `int` to `Program` class?! can you clarify please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The stack overflow is caused by this method calling itself infinitely:

```
public static implicit operator Program(int asd)
{ return 10; }
```

Why does this method call itself infinitely? Well, this method defines an implicit conversion from `int` to `Program`, so you are supposed to return a an instance of `Program` given an `int` called `asd`. However, you return an `int`. Normally, this would fail, but since you defined an implicit conversion from `int` to `Program`, the compiler goes "okay, that's fine".

But at runtime, it tries to convert your `10` to a `Program`, *by calling the implicit conversion method again*. The implicit conversion method returns a `10`, which the runtime tries to implicitly convert to `Program` again, so it calls the method again...

I don't really see what you are trying to do here, so I don't know what's a solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything! Well... almost - I thought the method is supposed to be called only once and the return value used, sort of, replacing the `(Program)3` part. Since I am not making an implicit conversion from the returned 10 to `Program`, why does it try to implicitly convert it again? Also - It's just for testing purposes, no solution for this problem required, just an explanation. :)

Comment: @J.Doe Are you aware that the method is supposed to return a `Program`, but you are returning an `int`?

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of that fact. Did I make you aware that this is a test program for test purposes just to test some stuff with no real application, expectation, goal or purpose?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes. So what do you expect the program to do when you are returning an `int` from a method that is declared to return a `Program`? Try to convert the `int` to a `Program`, of course! There is an implicit conversion defined for it! So the method gets called again.

Comment: See, that's the part that puzzles me, I expect the program to, quite literally, replace the `(Program)3` bit with just `10`. Since, in my mind, `(Program)3` is just a shorthand for (let's say the implicit conversion method is named "Convert") `Convert(3)`, which would just spit out 10 and be on its way. I am trying to understand the inner workings of this in-depth.

Comment: @J.Doe No, converting `3` to `10` is not a type conversion. They are both of type `int`. You can replace `10` with `new Program()` to get rid of the stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

If you define an implicit operator, it should return the type you specified, in this case it should be of type `Program`.

```
public static implicit operator Program(int asd)
{ return 10; }
```

What is happening here is that you return an integer. Normally that would simply not compile, because you should return a `Program`. However, since you have defined an implicit from `int` to `Program`, this is no problem; run time this conversion will be used to cast your `int` into  a `Program`.

However, this conversion does not return a `Program`, but an `int`, so the conversion is called again.

When executing `(Program)3`, this causes `(Program)10` to be called, which causes `(Program)10` to be called, ... which is an infinite loop.

Ask yourself what you are actually trying to do, and why you are returning an integer when you promise to return a `Program`.

Comment: Thanks, another very informative answer! But I'd like to ask you the same question I directed towards Sweeper - I thought the method is supposed to be called only once and the return value used, sort of, replacing the (Program)3 part, kind of literally replacing `(Program)3` with just `10`. Why does the compiler/program think I am making an implicit conversion from the returned 10 to Program?

Comment: The implicit operator you defined should not replace `(Program)3` with `10`, it is supposed to replace it with a `Program`. If you want to change one integer into another, do not use (implicit or explicit) conversions, just use a normal method.